# Expose only a subset of data to public but keep other data private

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am planning a `blockchain` based solution for supply chain management(SCM). There I want to give permission only to a set of known parties to write into the blockchain and expose only a subset of that data to the public (any random user). Can I achieve this with a `private-permissioned` blockchain such as `Hyperledger-Fabric` or should I go for a `hybrid blockchain`?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can achieve this in Fabric. Take a look at Fabric's Private Data Collection. It allows you to store a subset, or all of data in what we call a SideDB. The block is still committed to the chain, but no data defined in the Private Collection is stored on the chain. Instead it is stored in the Private Collection on the SideDB and only accessible to those designated in the Collections config.

Here is the official page: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html